# c++: finding pid of process started with system()

Tags: c++, system, fork

When using fork() to create a child process, we get the pid of the child such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8397816/984260) and many other places.

Is there a way that I can do the same with system() function? The reason I am looking in this is that, fork seems to slow down my program (fork may have overhead of 15-20 seconds), perhaps due to its overhead and I want to try if system() function avoids that.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I can't quite imagine why `fork` would take 15-20 seconds, but internally `system` is going to call `fork` (then `exec`), so any speedup from doing so would be *quite* unexpected. The obvious exception would be if you were running on something like Windows that doesn't actually support `fork` so it has to be simulated (at considerable expense), whereas `system` is supported more directly.

Comment: If not system, can you suggest some other alternative of fork, which may be fast.

Comment: Post your `fork` code, you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Why do you want get the PID of a process invoked via `system`? By the time `system` returns, the process will have terminated and the PID will no longer be useful.

Comment: There is no alternative. If you think your `fork()` is slow, ask a question about it, with all the supporting data.

Comment: More probably the new process you're creating is taking those 15-20 seconds to run, somehow. The fork() function is quite fast - consider that Apache Web Server uses it all the time (for instance, if you have wsgi each client connection will result in a fork() call to create a process that'll handle it) and feels almost instantaneous for the user, even in a low-end machine.

Comment: @FabioCeconello great to know that.

Comment: Thanks friends. I looked at the code at the code again. The overhead of fork is probably less than what I imagined.